How to Integrate Stalwart JMAP with ASP.NET Core Web API?
I am developing a client application in ASP.NET Core Web API and want to integrate JMAP functionality using Stalwart Mail Server. Specifically, I need guidance on:
Establishing connectivity between my API and Stalwart's JMAP implementation.
Sending requests and handling responses to/from Stalwart's JMAP server using JSON.
If anyone has successfully implemented this or has examples, I’d appreciate detailed guidance or sample code. Thank you!
I attempted to establish connectivity with Stalwart JMAP by sending requests using HttpClient in ASP.NET Core. I set the Content-Type header to application/json and tried querying the JMAP session endpoint (/.well-known/jmap).

...so what is the problem?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
